# CSS Modal Popup with optional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a CSS based modal popup with optional JavaScript? The solution should be mostly CSS based. I looked at some of the CSS only solutions, and they change the page URL. This question is intended to provide alternatives. For example, it's possible to create a CSS based modal popup with the `:active` and `:focus` selectors. It's also necessary to use the `object` tag for nesting anchors. A solution is posted below.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works by using the `:active`, `:focus` css selectors to show the modal. To hide the modal, focus is transferred to a different anchor from the one which triggered it. `object` tag is used to nest anchors. JavaScript is optional, but preferred, for best operation.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('no-drag'), l => l.addEventListener('dragstart', e => e.preventDefault())))
```

```css
body {
  background: #dfd;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: .2em;
  border: .2em solid;
  border-radius: .6em;
  padding: .3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'MS Shell Dlg 2', Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-green {
  border-color: #9b9;
  background-color: #686;
  color: #bdb;
}
.btn-green:hover {
  border-color: #9cb;
  background-color: #698;
  color: #bed;
}
.modal-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transition: visibility .5s;
  transition: visibility .5s;
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: .2em solid #9b9;
  border-radius: .6em;
  background-color: rgba(102, 136, 102, .8);
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s, right .5s, bottom .5s, left .5s;
  transition: top .5s, right .5s, bottom .5s, left .5s;
}
.modal-header, .modal-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  background-color: rgba(102, 136, 102, .8);
  padding: 0 .2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal-header {
  top: 1em;
}
.modal-footer {
  bottom: 1em;
}
.modal-text, .modal-btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: .2em;
  color: #bdb;
}
.modal-text {
  left: 0;
  padding: .1em .3em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.modal-btn {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: .6em;
  padding: .1em .6em;
  background-color: rgba(85, 119, 85, .8);
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modal-btn:hover, .modal-btn:active, .modal-btn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(119, 153, 136, .8);
  color: #ced;
}
.modal-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  right: 1em;
  bottom: 4em;
  left: 1em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: .5em;
}
.modal-show:active > .modal-container, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container {
  visibility: visible;
}
.modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  /* Extra Extra Small */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  /* Extra Small */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  /* Small */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: .5em;
    right: .5em;
    bottom: .5em;
    left: .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Medium */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: 1.5em;
    right: 1.5em;
    bottom: 1.5em;
    left: 1.5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  /* Large */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    bottom: 3em;
    left: 3em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* Extra Large */
  .modal-show:active > .modal-container > .modal, .modal-show:focus > .modal-container > .modal {
    top: 6em;
    right: 6em;
    bottom: 6em;
    left: 6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-green modal-show no-drag" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false" draggable="false">
  Modal
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <object class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-text">Modal Dialog</div>
        <a class="modal-btn" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">x</a>
      </object>
      <div class="modal-body">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec ornare nisi, ac aliquam erat. Vestibulum rhoncus, ipsum vitae lobortis pellentesque, odio lorem convallis lorem, nec malesuada dolor magna vitae metus. Duis varius mi vel nunc lobortis blandit. Duis eu posuere tortor. Etiam ac arcu finibus, suscipit sem nec, pulvinar enim. Aliquam pellentesque arcu nec sem iaculis, vitae convallis purus imperdiet. Aenean et dolor a nulla placerat facilisis eget non arcu.

Duis venenatis nulla nec augue vulputate, vel dapibus dui accumsan. Curabitur quis purus vitae lectus cursus fermentum at vehicula turpis. Ut vel facilisis mauris. Duis accumsan, enim sed egestas elementum, orci mi mollis tellus, vel luctus tortor augue gravida est. Nulla at lorem sed elit facilisis interdum. Duis mattis non sapien at laoreet. Sed suscipit elit ut tellus laoreet, sit amet gravida nunc mollis. Nam ullamcorper est quis facilisis scelerisque. Duis nulla diam, blandit sed commodo quis, blandit id felis. Nam eleifend elit et orci aliquet gravida. Donec at commodo diam. Proin vehicula auctor gravida.

Vivamus finibus tempus lobortis. Integer convallis neque non ex placerat porta. Fusce a purus maximus, sollicitudin libero eu, vulputate nibh. Nullam pulvinar enim et purus tincidunt porta. Mauris diam enim, volutpat quis urna sed, rhoncus convallis ante. Vestibulum mollis metus eu dui elementum varius. Vestibulum sodales massa eget viverra malesuada. Vestibulum eget lacinia nunc.

Donec mattis lobortis lorem ac tempor. Donec iaculis, felis eu imperdiet accumsan, ex neque laoreet velit, vitae egestas felis diam vitae massa. Aenean maximus magna velit, vel mattis tortor dapibus sed. Cras vehicula fringilla nulla, eget mattis nibh. Quisque lacinia convallis massa, a consectetur nibh viverra id. Donec quis mauris vitae mi rhoncus lacinia. Ut metus felis, cursus et risus at, fringilla mattis dui. Vestibulum sollicitudin facilisis hendrerit. Morbi a risus nisl. Donec sed gravida turpis. Nulla hendrerit dui mollis dui accumsan, eget facilisis metus vestibulum. Sed vel molestie eros. Quisque ut felis purus. Donec nec bibendum quam, ac accumsan risus. Donec blandit eu ante sollicitudin rutrum. In vitae iaculis est, ac molestie nunc.

Nunc eu justo id dui ultricies facilisis quis eu tortor. Phasellus eget nulla quis elit fringilla maximus. Suspendisse tortor justo, tempor vel accumsan in, suscipit non leo. Pellentesque non gravida sapien. Sed vel ex vel dui tempor pellentesque a eget elit. Pellentesque gravida ligula quis mollis vestibulum. Quisque a nibh id nibh mollis tincidunt. Proin ex eros, sagittis a tellus vel, auctor rutrum arcu. Integer quam erat, congue non tellus vitae, fermentum suscipit metus. Cras quis mi id ante maximus cursus sit amet ac libero.
      </div>
      <object class="modal-footer">
        <a class="modal-btn" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">Close</a>
      </object>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new HTML element called `<dialog>`. Its [support is quite recent](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog) but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill).

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Here is an example for you:

```html
<dialog id="my-dialog">
  <p>Hello from my dialog</p>
  <button id="hide-button">Hide dialog</button>
</dialog>

<button id="show-button">Show dialog</button>

<script>
  const showButton = document.querySelector('#show-button');
  const hideButton = document.querySelector('#hide-button');
  const dialog = document.querySelector('#my-dialog');
  showButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  hideButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dialog.close();
  });
</script>
```